# Pass JSON array from Javascript to PHP and convert to csv

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, csv

I am attempting to create a .csv file from a JSON array passed into a php file from JavaScript after submit event is detected in the page.

I am to the point where I can see the array coming back from the JavaScript as JSON... It is passing it to the php file, and then having the php file parse the object and output it into a .csv file

I've included the HTML, JavaScript, and php that I'm using to make it this far... Can I get pointed in the right direction?

The errors I get vary with the following:

When I attempt to inject my array manually:

```
http://localhost/~admin/dev/parse.php?submittedResults=[[%22uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg%22,%22featured%22]]

[Sat Jan 04 22:12:29 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents($path): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 62
[Sat Jan 04 22:12:29 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(clients/downloads/csv/[[&quot;uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg&quot;,&quot;featured&quot;]].csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 65
[Sat Jan 04 22:12:29 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 66
[Sat Jan 04 22:12:29 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 69
```

When I attempt to let JavaScript to do the array passing:

```
[Sat Jan 04 22:15:36 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 57, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:15:36 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents($path): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 62, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:15:36 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(clients/downloads/csv/Array.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 65, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:15:36 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 66, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:15:36 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 69, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
```

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit"">
      <div class="imageTile">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="rel" href="uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg"><img src="uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg" style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 110px;"></a><br>
        <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg">
        <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="featured">
        <label for="uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg">Keep<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="imageTile">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="rel" href="uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg"><img src="uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg" style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 110px;"></a><br>
        <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageFilename" value="uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg">
        <input class="data" type="hidden" name="imageGalleryID" value="featured">
        <label for="uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg">Keep<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="submit_buttons">
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" onclick="return false" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.submit').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var imageTile = this.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('imageTile');
    var l = imageTile.length;
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if (imageTile[i].getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0].checked) {
            var dat = imageTile[i].getElementsByClassName('data');
            console.log(dat);
            var ll = dat.length;
            var datArr = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < ll; j++) {
                datArr.push(dat[j].attributes['value'].value);
            }
            data.push(datArr);
        }
    }
    // Now 'data' is the array

    // dataString is a JSON representation of the array to send to the server
    var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

    // Test
    console.log(data);
    console.log(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'parse.php?submittedResults' + dataString,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).done(function(data) {

    })
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['submittedResults'])) {
    if (empty($_GET['submittedResults'])) {
        die('Give me something to work with!!');
    }
    $resultSet = (string) $_GET['submittedResults'];
    $path = $resultSet;
    if (strpos($path, '../') !== false || strpos($path, "..\\") !== false || strpos($path, '/..') !== false || strpos($path, '\..') !== false) {
        http_response_code(403);
    } else {
        $getFile = file_get_contents('$path');
        $json_obj = json_decode($getFile);
        echo "$json_obj";
        $fp = fopen("clients/downloads/csv/$path.csv", 'w');
        foreach ($json_obj as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
[["uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg","featured"],["uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg","featured"]]
```

So I did notice I was missing the '=' sign... I redid the ajax call to match what you suggested, the behavior is the same. I also included the echo as requested below here are the results:

The requested echo:

```
 var_dump($_GET['submittedResults'])

string(101) "[["uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg","featured"],["uploads/featured/doublewm-3935.jpg","featured"]]"
```

The current Logs:

```
[Sat Jan 04 22:27:43 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents($path): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 63, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:27:43 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(clients/downloads/csv/[[&quot;uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg&quot;,&quot;featured&quot;],[&quot;uploads/featured/doublewm-3935.jpg&quot;,&quot;featured&quot;]].csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 66, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:27:43 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 67, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:27:43 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 70, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
```

Current JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'parse.php',
    data: { submittedResults: JSON.stringify(data) },
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
}).
```

Comment: I do not get the .csv file as expected... I am fairly positive the array is making it back into the php script

Comment: You need to be explain what is not working, be detailed, add it to your post

Comment: fairly positive eh? Lets test that. `var_dump($_GET['submittedResults'])`

Comment: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/parse.php?submittedResults[[%22uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg%22,%22featured%22],[%22uploads/featured/doublewm-3935.jpg%22,%22featured%22]]

string(101) "[["uploads/featured/doublewm-3683.jpg","featured"],["uploads/featured/doublewm-3935.jpg","featured"]]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents($path): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 62

```
$resultSet = (string) $_GET['submittedResults'];
$path = $resultSet;
```

this is causing you a problem because $path is equal to the json data.
Which is wrong, path should be a filename. Try like this :

```
//$resultSet =(string) $_GET['submittedResults'];
$resultSet = '[["uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg","featured"],
           ["uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg","featured"]]';
$path = "myfile.csv"; //or clients/downloads/csv/myfile.csv
if (strpos($path, '../') !== false || strpos($path, "..\\") !== false 
  || strpos($path, '/..') !== false || strpos($path, '\..') !== false) {
    http_response_code(403);
} else {
    $json_obj = json_decode($resultSet);
    echo "$json_obj";
    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');
    foreach ($json_obj as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

---

myfile.csv :

```
uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg,featured
uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg,featured
```

EDIT:
Give a unique filename

```
$json_obj = json_decode($resultSet);
$path = $json_obj[0][1].".csv";
```

output

`featured.csv`

Comment: [Sat Jan 04 22:41:07 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(myfile.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 64, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:41:07 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: json_obj in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 65, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:41:07 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 65, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm

Comment: @user3161804 I put the full code, you can test it like this `$resultSet = '[["uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg","featured"],["uploads/featured/moon-5469.jpg","featured"]]';` also you dont need `file_get_contents` at all

Comment: I tried with and without the result set hard coded the errors are the same

Comment: [Sat Jan 04 22:48:21 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 65, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:48:21 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fopen(clients/downloads/csv/myfile.csv): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 66, referer: http://localhost/~Admin/dev/index.htm
[Sat Jan 04 22:48:21 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  fputcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/Admin/Sites/dev/parse.php on line 68

Comment: I just tried it it works on my PC, the last error you posted show that the problem is when you cast it to a string `(string) $_GET['submittedResults'];`, I would hardcoded to make sure it work, then troubleshoot your way out

Comment: @user3161804 Also in PHP you shouldnt worry about variable types, `$resultSet = $_GET['submittedResults'];` should be just fine

Comment: Is this expecting that a file called myfile.csv to exist before adding content to it? ... I'm still getting permission denied on the fopen

Comment: If it does not exist then it creates it, otherwise it writes to it

Comment: This worked, thank you turned out it was file permissions to be the error.

Comment: by chance would you know how to use the "featured" from the first key value pair as the .csv filename when it creates it? This will change which each submission so ideally it would be unique 

out of a string like this:
'[["uploads/featured/doublewm-4097.jpg","featured"],["uploads/featured/moon-5469‌​.jpg","featured"]]';

Comment: I didnt get it, what do you want to be unique, give me an example

Comment: In each object of the JSON array you have "filepath: galleryID"... the galleryID will change with the gallery being viewed. I would like to name the csv file after the galleryID being passed in the first JSON object. 
aka:
Not have a hardcoded $path value of "myfile.csv" rather have it be dynamic with the galleryID being passed, ie: featured, gallery1, gallery2... resulting in gallery1.csv, gallery2.csv, featured.csv

Comment: @user3161804 I added some code, you will have to tweak your script tho, because you can only create the path variable after parsing the JSON, Ok my friend Im out to the bar!!